# Google Maps API - Intranet

Tags: google-maps

I have an internal network with only the web server connected to the internet. How can the server serve google maps pages to all the machines on this internal network? The way I understand the maps api is called from the client and hence either the maps server has to be on the internal network (Business License) or all machines should have internet access.

Comment: I don't think this is actually possible to do - I was going to suggest using a proxy on your server, and this will work for the initial request of the api script file. However, the api script then makes requests for each tile on google maps and you'd need to be connected to the internet for that to happen.